# Why this cooking pot not working on my Induction?

Tags: equipment, wok, pot, induction

I just bought this Induction compatible Kadai (kind of wok) but surprised to know it's not working.

When I place it over my Induction cooker, it doesn't show any error (*generally if a pot is not compatible or not placed properly shows error E0 in red text with a continuous beeping sound of delay 1-2 seconds*) but heating starts and stops for 1 second alternatively. Also when it starts and stops next second, the display board of temperature blinks. **For example, if the reading is 1000, it will show 1000 then next second it blinks with a cracking/glitch sound and it keeps on like that.** It seems like it *wants* to heat but something is not working.

Here is the image of Prestige induction I'm using:

[image]

One thing I noticed with this wok is the base is slightly concave from bottom. I mean when you place a straight scale on base, it touches the edges only, not the central part. Same when I place it on induction. But outer ring touches it completely.

Can this concave thing be the reason for its not working?

Another possible problem can be because of size? I measured the following area of my wok:

[image: cook]

It almost superimposes the circular mark made on Induction stove. If it is slightly bigger (which I may have not noticed), can this be the reason for it not working?

EDIT: I noticed a strange thing today. I ordered another Wok (bit smaller) today from a reputed brand in India. Sadly, same problem happened with it. But with this wok, I tried to boil water. And once water started heating (due to partial working it got heated), the error which *wanted* to show disappeared. Why would it happen? And once it is cold, the problem started again.

Here is the image of the same:

[image]

Here are two pots that work without any problem:
*(Their base is plain/flat). Not patterns like the ones on Wok bottoms)*

One of the pots' base is concave but still works. The other one is very flat.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you tell us about the other wok you just bought? Is the size similar? Does it also have a concave bottom? How are the two pans which don't work different from other pans which have worked in the past?

Comment: @Kat please check my edit.

Comment: @Kat I bought this today https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MCEcmWGhdlSTcHOdY_2kO47XGt18TZU7 and it works. Not a wok but bottom is similar. Major difference in bottom is it is flat, not concave. Is that the reason?

Answer (score 3):

An induction pan must be flat to work properly, if it is bowed up in the middle even if it does work you aren't going to have the right efficiency. Many pans say induction ready, some say it because they are made of steel or iron, but not all of them have been tested so you won't always know before you try it.

Comment: I noticed a strange thing today. I ordered another Wok today from a reputed brand in India. Sadly, same problem happened with it. I tried to boil water. But once water started heating (due to partial working it got heated), the error which *wanted* to show disappeared. Why would it happen? And once it is cold, the problem started again.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a steel pan ? Test with a magnet. (I think my cheap induction hob came with a cheap magnet thingy to test my pans)

"Cast iron, enameled cast iron, and many types of stainless-steel cookware are all induction compatible. There are exceptions, though. For instance, All-Clad's MC2 line, which is made of aluminum and stainless steel, is not induction compatible. Stainless steel poses the most confusion because it can be made with a great variety of metals; a high nickel content will block the magnetic field."

"Aluminum, all-copper, or glass cookware will not work unless they have a layer on the bottom with magnetic properties."

https://www.thespruceeats.com/what-is-the-best-cookware-for-induction-cooktops-908920

Comment: Isn't it necessary for the entire base area to touch the induction surface?

Comment: also I just use a small magnet near it. It is sticking. I compared the magnetic strength with other pot which is working fine, and both seems equal. I guess the contact area is bigger then the circle made on Induction cooker?

Comment: No, I can use my warped carbon steel pan on my cheap hub; maybe less efficient, but it works.

Comment: I noticed a strange thing today. I ordered another Wok today from a reputed brand in India. Sadly, same problem happened with it. I tried to boil water. But once water started heating (due to partial working it got heated), the error which *wanted* to show disappeared. Why would it happen? And once it is cold, the problem started again.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit surprised by your description of the error state - all induction stoves start and stop heating all the time, beyond the 50 Hertz cycle of the electricity they also use time modulation on a more noticeable frequency to control their energy output. But you speak as if you have had been using the stove for a while, so it must be different from the normal heat/no neat cycle - maybe you can describe in more detail what is happening.

Having a rim is not necessarily a problem, but maybe it contributes to it in this case, I can't say for sure.

I used to cook on induction, and I had a small American cast iron with a rim on the bottom. It always worked great - in induction, you don't need the pan to touch the cooking surface. But induction cookers have a "pan detection" mechanism, and maybe your pan is constructed in such a way that your stove has trouble detecting it properly.

In the end, if a given pan doesn't work with a given stove, there is nothing to do but retire the pan.

Comment: Kindly check the edit.

Comment: I noticed a strange thing today. I ordered another Wok today from a reputed brand in India. Sadly, same problem happened with it. I tried to boil water. But once water started heating (due to partial working it got heated), the error which *wanted* to show disappeared. Why would it happen? And once it is cold, the problem started again.

Comment: I cannot say for sure why it happened. Three possible reasons are 1) that the sensor in your cooktop is not very well implemented and for some reason doesn't recognize the pan properly, 2) that the pan is not actually well suited for induction (e.g. they lied when saying that they have built in a steel layer, or they have made it so small that it doesn't actually work), or 3) that there is a defect in your induction unit. The third one is unlikely, since you are saying that other pots still work. I would suggest that you buy a normal wok, and test it with a magnet.

Comment: Another strange thing today @rumtscho I bought another cookware for another need. Here's the picture. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MCEcmWGhdlSTcHOdY_2kO47XGt18TZU7

 But this works without any problem. The brand is same, but the base is not concave like Wok. So that can be the reason? Flat things work better than concave?

Answer (score 0):

An induction hob works by heating only the base of a pan - the heat doesn’t go on up the sides of a pan. So a wok with wide spreading sides is not very practical. I use a cast iron deep sided pan when I do stir fry menus.

Comment: Okay but why would a reputed company manufacture it then for induction?

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B00QWQ1V86/ref=ask_ql_qh_dp_hza